# Explanation for $\lim_{x\to2} e^{\frac{1}{x-2}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't find out why is the limit from the left side = 0 and from the right = Infinity[image]?

Comment: Welcome to math.se! What have you worked out so far?

Comment: I tried to approximate it using a calculator, and for the right side I get Infinity, but I can't figure out how did the result stated 0 for the left side.

Comment: Let $x=1.99$. Then $e^{1/(x-2)}=e^{-100}$, that is, $\frac{1}{e^{100}}$, which is very close to $0$. Now look at $x=1.999$.

Answer (score 1):

First look at $\dfrac1{x-2}$. It has a vertical asymptote at $x=2$, thus $-\infty$ /$+\infty$ left and right limits. Taking the exponential, limits are obviously $0$ and $+\infty$ (think that $e^x$ grows very fast and $e^{-x}=1/e^x$).

The behavior of the function at $2^-$ is very special, as it tends to $0$ extremely fast because of the exponential, and it turns out that the left derivatives of all orders are $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $u = 1 / (x - 2)$, so that $$\lim_{x \to 2^{\pm}} = \pm \infty.$$
Then,
$$\lim_{x \to 2^{\pm}} e^{1 / (x - 2)} = \lim_{u \to \pm \infty} e^u.$$

Comment: When I tried that I was stuck because I don't know to prove from that step what is $$e^{\pm \infty }$$ as I wrote, I could only approximate it.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that in the first expression the power of $e$ decreases without bounds, while in the second expression the power of $e$ increases without bounds. Then consider the graph of $e^x$.

P.S.: Calculators tend to lie, I suggest you do not rely on them.